# Get Max and Min in a single LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a set of objects with two properties, A and B. I'd like to get the Min of A and the Max of B.

eg

```
var minA = objects.Min(o => o.A);
var maxB = objects.Max(o => o.B);
```

Using LINQ query syntax, is there a way to do this so it only passes over the set once?

Desired outcome would be an anonymous type (eg, results.MinA = x, results.MaxB = y)

Comment: Why don't you write your own extension method that walks once through the object range and returns a `Tuple<min,max>` or something?

Comment: This is close to a guess, so I apologize, but getting min and maz during one pass would be something like like this.: if num > max then max. else if num < min, then min. I'm not sure if that is all that more efficient then going through the collection twice. Just throwing that out there.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Min and Max are both aggregates. The general linq aggregate function is [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Assuming property A is an integer, and B is a string, you could write something like this:

```
objects.Aggregate(
    new {
        MinA = int.MaxValue,
        MaxB = string.Empty
    },
    (accumulator, o) => new {
        MinA = Math.Min(o.A, accumulator.MinA),
        MaxB = o.B > accumulator.MaxB ? o.B : accumulator.MaxB
    });
```

Comment: Of course, I forget that in c# strings don't have a `>` operator, but its just for illustration.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Aggregate` method.

```
var res = new { Min = objects[0].A, Max = objects[0].B }
var res = objects.Aggregate(res, (r, curr) => r.Min = r.Min < curr.A ? r.Min : curr.A; r.Max = r.Max > curr.B ? r.Max : curr.B);
```

Comment: The question asks for "LINQ query syntax" (as oppose to the lambda extension methods) ... not sure if that was important to cyrus or not.

Comment: @MattTester I assumed he wanted single pass first and query style second,

Answer (score 3):

I know you wanted a Linq query, but I can't stop pointing out the non-linq version may be much more **readable**. Compare this:

```
IEnumerable<Message> messages = SomeMessages();

Func<DateTime, DateTime, DateTime> min = (dt1, dt2) => dt1 > dt2 ? dt2 : dt1;
Func<DateTime, DateTime, DateTime> max = (dt1, dt2) => dt1 > dt2 ? dt1 : dt2;

// linq version
var result = messages.Aggregate(
    new { StartDate = DateTime.MaxValue, EndDate = DateTime.MinValue }, /* initial value */
    (accumulate, current) => new { StartDate = min(accumulate.StartDate, current.ReceivedTime), EndDate = max(accumulate.EndDate, current.ReceivedTime) });

// non-linq version
DateTime start = DateTime.MaxValue;
DateTime end = DateTime.MinValue;
foreach (DateTime dt in messages.Select(msg => msg.ReceivedTime))
{
    start = min(start, dt);
    end = max(end, dt);
}
```

Comment: The LINQ version is more readable because as you read down the source code, you don't have to refer back to variables and other state that you need to keep track in your head.   When the code is transforming data, your eyes just follow where the data is getting transformed.   It's like a story in a book.. you read left to right, up and down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `YourObject` as a container for the results, and use `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` to tidy the syntax:

```
var maxmin = objects.Aggregate(objects[0], (i, j) =>
            new YourObject { A = Math.Min(i.A, j.A), B = Math.Max(i.B, j.B) });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get min and max values from object list (and you dont want to group by property) than you could use this linq:

```
var val = new List<dynamic>{
    new { A=1, B=1 },
    new { A=2, B=2 },
    new { A=3, B=4 }
}; 

var minMax = val.GroupBy(f => string.Empty).Select(f => new
{
    Min = f.Min(g => g.A),
    Max = f.Max(g => g.B)
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Okay, understand now, the keyword is "passes over the set once".

Comment: Min and Max are abstraction of aggregate and both of them implements internal foreach (means 2 round-trips). With aggregate solved by @Cirdec is totally better approach.  
`val.Aggregate(
 (min: int.MinValue, max: int.MaxValue),
 (accumulator, o) => (min: Math.Min(o.A, accumulator.min), max: Math.Max(o.B, accumulator.max)));`

Comment: unless you're using linq-to-entity in which case `.Aggregate` could complain about translating whatever you put in place of Math.Min if you're trying to take min/max of Dates for example - this is the better approach if your expression is being translated into SQL

Answer (score 0):

Depending on definition on single linq query this is a decent fit for an extension method.

```
public static MinAndMax<T> MinAndMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    Ensure.NotNullOrEmpty(source, nameof(source));
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var min = enumerator.Current;
            var max = enumerator.Current;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(enumerator.Current, min) < 0)
                {
                    min = enumerator.Current;
                }

                if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(enumerator.Current, max) > 0)
                {
                    max = enumerator.Current;
                }
            }

            return new MinAndMax<T>(min, max);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements.");
    }
}

public struct MinAndMax<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public MinAndMax(T min, T max)
    {
        this.Min = min;
        this.Max = max;
    }

    public T Min { get; }

    public T Max { get; }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var minMax = xs.MinAndMax();
```

Comment: Why introduce a new type, and not use a `ValueTuple<T, T>`? `public static (T Min, T Max) MinAndMax<T>...`

Comment: For a public method I prefer a named type but I'm old. Tuple with named fields is an alternative. No huge downside with a small trivial struct.

Answer (score -1):

There are new helpers for LINQ in .NET 6 for this matter: MaxBy and MinBy

```
var people = GetPeople();

var oldest = people.MaxBy(p => p.Age);
var youngest = people.MinBy(p => p.Age);

Console.WriteLine($"The oldest person is {oldest.Age}");
Console.WriteLine($"The youngest person is {youngest.Age}");
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question: there are two passes over the sequence here.

Answer (score -4):

Something like this will work for you
My previous answer didn't work,

I went back and tried a couple of the different answers here and ended up with this solution, suggested previously

```
        var values = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        var maxmin = new {min = values.Min(), max = values.Max()};
```

Comment: Doesn't differ at all from non-optimized solution.

Comment: It doesn't actually work as `o` is not `IEnumerable`, etc and so doesn't have the `Min` or `Max` functions. Therefore it won't build the line `let min = o.Min(o => o.A)`