# How to get the maximum/minimum value from a SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have built a `SortedDictionary<int, FlowLayoutPanel> panels` as prescribed. I currently am looping over the dictionary like so

```
foreach (var key in panels.Keys.ToList())
{
    FlowLayoutPanel tallestPanel = panels[key];
}
```

to get the entry with the maximum key value. I am trying to now write another loop that continually applies an operation until the `Count` of the dictionary is 0. Within this loop I need to get the maximum and minimum value from the dictionary on each iteration. I have read over the [`SortedDictionary` MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) entry and it looks like I need to use linq to accomplish this. Is this true? How would I do that? (I've never touched linq)

And a bonus question that I can't find a good answer to, do `SortedDictionaries` sort from largest to smallest value i.e. if the `int` in `<int, FlowLayoutPanel>` represented the `FlowLayoutPanels.Height`, would the loop above continually give me the tallest panel?

Comment: LINQ is not necessary for doing this. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240167/get-max-and-min-in-a-single-linq-query for an elegant LINQ solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the keys are sorted in `panels.Keys`, the minimum and maximum keys will simply be the first and last items in `panels.Keys`. You don't need LINQ to do this:

```
var keys = panels.Keys.ToList();
// manually-determined indexes
var min = panels[keys[0]];
var max = panels[keys[keys.Count - 1]];
```

Although arguably, it's clearer if you use it:

```
var keys = panels.Keys.ToList();
// or with LINQ
var min = panels[keys.First()];
var max = panels[keys.Last()];
```

If you want to get these values from inside a loop that's looping through `panel.Keys.ToList()` and removing each item from the dictionary as it goes (which is what I think you're describing), the minimum is always the current, and the maximum is always the last.

```
var keys = panels.Keys.ToList();
var max = panels[keys.Last()];
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    var min = panels[key];
    // do stuff
    panels.Remove(min);
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that the `ToList()` call makes this O(n)?

Comment: @GáborBakos I wasn't really; good to know. However, if you're removing items from the dictionary inside a `foreach`, you can't just use the [`KeyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132264(v=vs.110).aspx) directly.

Comment: Not only is ToList() O(n) but also causes allocation. This is helplessly inefficient. It should come with a giant disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

You can get `First` and `Last` Key from the `SortedDictionary` which would be minimum and maximum respectively.

```
int minKey = 0;
int maxKey = 0;
if (panels.Keys.Count >= 2)
{
    minKey = panels.Keys.First();
    maxKey = panels.Keys.Last();
}
```

You can also use `Enumerable.Min` and `Enumerable.Max` like:

```
minKey = panels.Keys.Min();
maxKey = panels.Keys.Max();
```

Comment: Would it not be enough to check when `Keys.Count` is not `0`? (`First()` and `Last()` of one element can be computed.)

Comment: Don't forget to `using System.Linq;`