# Using Parallel.For for searching for minimum/maximum value

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

```cs
object _ = new object();
List<int> list = new List<int>(new int {1,25,3....18,255}); //random values
int bestIndex = 0;
int bestValue = int.MinValue;
Parallel.For(0, list.Length, (i) => {
    if (list[i] > bestValue)
    {
        lock (_)
        {
            bestValue = list[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
});
```

My question is, does it make sense. Because I suspect that simply in certain scenarios lower value will be assigned even though it shouldn't.

Comment: Using `lock` may easily defeat any TPL gain. Rather try [this linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22240385/1997232).

Comment: What you describe is a job for PLINQ, not `Parallel`. `list.AsParellel.Max()` is not just simpler but *faster* than what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is not threadsafe since you are reading and writing to the same value from multiple threads. If you fix this and put the check inside the lock you do not gain any parellelism, and worse, are using a highly contended lock in a very tight loop, this will most likely cause significant overhead. I would also recommend against using `_` as a varable name, since it is used for [Discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) in c#7.

The correct solution is to run multiple independent searches in parallel, and then do a final comparison of the results from each thread.

```
         var globalMin = int.MaxValue;
         var lockObj = new object();
         Parallel.ForEach(list,
             // LocalInit, runs once for each thread
             () => int.MaxValue, 
             // The parallel body, runs on multiple threads
             (value, _, localMin) =>
             {
                 if (value < localMin)
                 {
                     return value;
                 }
                 return localMin;
             }, 
             // Local finally, runs once for each thread,
             // given the final result produced on that thread
             localMin =>
             {
                 lock (lockObj)
                 {
                     if (localMin < globalMin)
                     {
                         globalMin = localMin;
                     }
                 }

             });
         return globalMin;
```

This is however a bit long and complex, an alternative would be to use linq:

```
list.AsParallel().Min();
```

**edit:**
I wanted to add that using a parallel algorithm for such a simple task is unlikely to gain much performance, at least for primitive types. Running things in parallel is most useful when doing a decent amount of work at a time, so that the synchronization overhead remains a small proportion of the overall work. You might do some manual partitioning of the list to ensure each iteration does more work to improve performance a bit. But unless you have a really huge list it is usually not worth the effort.

Comment: I am not sure that the lock is used in a tight loop, in the OP's code. The lock is only acquired when a larger value has been found. Which should happen, if my math are correct (probably aren't), around `log2(list.Count)` times on average.

Comment: @theodor Zoulias , yes, but the code is incorrect, the check must be done inside the lock for it to be threadsafe. In most cases I would say that taking a lock inside a parallel loop is an indication you are doing something wrong.

Comment: True, the code is incorrect, but it does not generate high contention for the lock. Of course correctness is more important than performance, but it should be clarified IMHO that the "tight loop" refers to a hypothetical correct version of the code, not to its current state.

Answer (score 2):

`Parallel.For` wasn't built for such operations. That's the job of PLINQ. You can replace your code with just :

```
var min=list.AsParallel().Min();
```

This won't need any locks. It will partition the data into roughly as many partitions as there are cores, find the minimum in each partition then calculate the minimum across all partition minimums.

By not synchronizing with one global lock, this will result in near-optimal performance

Answer (score 1):

On top of what JonasH said in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65721568/11178549), I would like to add that using the `Parallel` class without specifying the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) through the [`ParallelOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions) is not a good idea. The default `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is `-1`, which means unbounded parallelism, in practice bounded by the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) availability. In other words calling any method of the `Parallel` class results (by default) to the `ThreadPool` becoming saturated for the whole duration of the parallel execution. Having a saturated `ThreadPool` is problematic when there are *other* parallel/asynchronous operations also happening concurrently. As an example the `Elapsed` event of the [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) class is invoked on the `ThreadPool`, so this event will behave hectically during the `Parallel` execution, because there will be no available `ThreadPool` thread to serve the event handler in a timely manner.

Here is how to configure the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of a `Parallel` loop, in order to mitigate the `ThreadPool`-starvation problem:

```
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};
Parallel.ForEach(list, parallelOptions, // ... It's OK now
```

In the above example the `Parallel.ForEach` loop will use concurrently at maximum `Environment.ProcessorCount - 1` thread-pool threads, plus the current thread.

This advice does not apply to [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq), which has a default max degree of parallelism equal to the number of the logical processors of the machine.