# Parallel for loop with conditional update of object declared outside loop

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am new to parallel programming in C#. I would really appreciate help on how to make the following serial for loop snippet parallel.

I have looked at the other questions on this topic but they either update simple types or arrays. Also, the questions I found do not have a conditional update on the object outside the for a loop.

Note specifically, contrary to answers to similar questions, I am looking to find a certain OBJECT (not simply a double or int) from the list, based on a property that also needs to be calculated/updated inside the loop, and then, based on that property ('fitness') I need to decide whether or not to update an object outside the loop.

This is for a genetic algorithm:

```
fitnessSum = 0;
DNA<T> best = Population[0];

//loop over the population
for (int i = 0; i < Population.Count; i++)
{
     //Get the fitness of the current candidate
     double fitnessThisPopulation = Population[i].CalculateFitness(i);                
     fitnessSum += fitnessThisPopulation;

     // If the current candidate has a better fitness, then update best fitness
     if (Population[i].fitness > best.fitness)
     {
         best = Population[i];
     }
}

BestFitness = best.fitness;
```

Any help is much appreciated. As an ex FORTRAN person, I am not an expert in Linq so I would prefer to code more along with the traditional for loop style. Many thanks!

Comment: I'd be inclined to batch the population and run each batch in parallel. Each batch could then have its own "best" and own "sum" values, which you could then combine in serial code at the end.

Comment: Any sensible example should be fine - there is no difference of what type of objects you update in parallel - you need to lock around access to shared data (or `Interlocked.*` methods if you know what you are doing)... Maybe if you [edit] the question to show your attempt and why do you think it is wrong it would be easier to provide good useful answer. (And I agree with @Llama that some rethinking of the approach could be useful - contention on updates may cost too much for such simple looking code)

Comment: is `CalculateFitness` a trivial calculation? also what is the size of the array you are working with ? also why are passing the index into `CalculateFitness` ?

Comment: @TheGeneral - Calculate fitness involves another loop with some sums and conditions. It is not a trivial function. The reason the index is passed into CalculateFitness is because that function needs to extract some properties from the object at index = i. I hope that clarifies things?

Comment: Could you include the `CalculateFitness` method in the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Parallel.For for searching for minimum/maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721017/using-parallel-for-for-searching-for-minimum-maximum-value)

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri - thanks will check that answer out tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri - I don't think the answer you suggested helps me. It is not updating an object. It is just calculating and comparing a basic type. Apologies if my interpretation is incorrect because of my lack of experience with parallel code, but that is my interpretation.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - the Calculate Fitness function will depend on the type of problem the Genetic Algorithm is trying to solve. It could be a simple formula such as y = f(x) but in my problem domain it will involve looping over a set of objects (identified by the index i) and then calculating a sum or a conditional sum etc. It is implemented separately from the code I show above and it only reads object properties, nothing is being updated on the objects in the CalculateFitness loop. I hope that helps

Comment: So you say that the `CalculateFitness` method, apart from returning a `double` value, does not mutate in any way the state of the application? Or in other words, it is completely side-effect free?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - yes that is correct. It is simply a number cruncher operating on lists and calculating a double as a result

Comment: This line is confusing: `if (Population[i].fitness > best.fitness)`. If you already know beforehand the `fitness` of each element in the `Population` array, then why do you have to call `CalculateFitness` previously? (taking as a given that the `CalculateFitness` is side-effect free, and so it doesn't mutate the state of the invoked element).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I do NOT know beforehand the fitness of each element. It is calculated inside the for loop, just before doing the comparison. That is the most expensive operation, hence my wanting to get it into parallel processing.

Comment: So what is this line doing? `if (Population[i].fitness > best.fitness)` Where is the value of the `fitness` property/field coming from, if it's not known beforehand, and also it's not mutated by the `CalculateFitness` invocation? Honestly it would be much easier for all of us if you could provide a minimal and compilable example showing a sequential execution, so that we can offer specific advices on how to parallelize it. This question in its current state is not answerable IMHO.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - my apologies - my answer earlier was not correct. Calculate fitness DOES mutate the state of individual objects in the Population list when it updates the Fitness property of each object in Population. I meant to say it does not modify any elements other than those in the list of objects. The answer below solved my problem and I have marked it as such.

Comment: Well, writing correct multithreaded code is all about identifying side-effects, and carefully crafting an implementation that prevents them from corrupting the state of the application. A single uncontrolled piece of "side-effecty" code is enough to invalidate an otherwise masterful implementation, and make the behavior of the program undefined. That's why we need to see the code, and not just a description of the code.

Comment: By the way the method `CalculateFitness` is invoked with the `i` as argument. Why does this method need to know the invoked object's position inside the `Population` list? Is it possible that the `CalculateFitness` reads the `fitness` property of other objects in the list?

Comment: Another question: how many objects are stored in the `Population` list? Not the exact number, just a rough estimation.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, fully agree with "carefully crafting an implementation". However, when posting a question, I have to make a judgement call about how much code to include. I do this on a judgement of what I think is informative and what is not, or, what can lead to confusion. In this case, showing you the code for my method CalculateFitness is in my judgement, not relevant. The code involves inherited abstract classes with complex domain specific (civil engineering) functions. It is IMO not relevant to the question. But I thank you for your interest and advice - it is really appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238161/discussion-between-fritz45-and-theodor-zoulias).

Comment: Fritz45 fair enough. But if the judgement call is not to the point for whatever reason, you may get generic answers that don't address the specifics of your problem, and also you may get fewer answers than you would otherwise get. Btw I don't think that the discussion belongs to the chat. All the clarifications that I've asked are essential for anyone who would like to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `CalculateFitness` is complex and the number of iterations large, then any partitioning strategy is likely to give you a performance gain. However, if it's trivial it's going to be harder to get a significant gain as the cost of spinning up tasks and threads are going to outweigh the actual JIT optimized iteration of the array.

So this answer isn't about what's faster, who knows, it depends on your system, cores, CPU, data, framework, calculations, and what day of the week it is.... however it shows you how you can test this yourself with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). I have included a *PLinq* (parallel partitioned) calculation for comparison:

**Given**

```
public class DNA
{
   public double fitness;

   public double CalculateFitness(int i)
   {
      // some weird complex sum
      var result = fitness;
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
         result += result-i;
      return result;
   }
}
```

**Benchmark Code**

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net50)]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Test
{
   private DNA[] _population;
   [Params(100000, 1000000)] public int N;

   [GlobalSetup]
   public void Setup()
   {
      var r = new Random(42);
      _population = Enumerable
         .Range(0, N)
         .Select(x => new DNA
         {
            fitness = r.Next(0, 10000)
         }).ToArray();
   }
      
   [Benchmark]
   public void New()
   {
      var fitnessSum = _population
         .AsParallel()
         .Select((x, i) => x.CalculateFitness(i))
         .Sum();

      var best = _population
         .AsParallel()
         .Max(x => x.fitness);
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public void New2()
   {
      var fitnessSum = _population
         .AsParallel()
         .Select((x, i) => x.CalculateFitness(i))
         .Sum();

      var best = _population
         .Max(x => x.fitness);
   }
      
   [Benchmark]
   public void New3()
   {
       var best = _population[0].fitness;

      var fitnessSum = _population
         .AsParallel()
         .Select((x, i) =>
         {
            AssignIfNewValueGreater(ref best, _population[i].fitness);
            return x.CalculateFitness(i);
         })
         .Sum();

   }

   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
   public static void AssignIfNewValueGreater(ref double target, double newValue)
   {
      // be careful, this method is only good for 64 operating systems
      double temp;
      do
      {
         temp = target;
      } while (newValue > temp && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref target, newValue, temp) != temp);
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public void Old()
   {
      double fitnessSum = 0;
      var best = _population[0];

      //loop over the population
      for (var i = 0; i < _population.Length; i++)
      {
         //Get the fitness of the current candidate
         var fitnessThisPopulation = _population[i].CalculateFitness(i);
         fitnessSum += fitnessThisPopulation;

         //If the current candidate has a better fitness, then update best fitness
         if (_population[i].fitness > best.fitness) best = _population[i];
      }

      var bestFitness = best.fitness;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
BenchmarkRunner.Run<Test>();
```

**Results**

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1288 (21H1/May2021Update)
AMD Ryzen 9 3900X, 1 CPU, 24 logical and 12 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.100-rc.1.21463.6
  [Host]   : .NET 5.0.11 (5.0.1121.47308), X64 RyuJIT  [AttachedDebugger]
  .NET 5.0 : .NET 5.0.11 (5.0.1121.47308), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET 5.0  Runtime=.NET 5.0
```

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New | 100000 | 8.082 ms | 0.1616 ms | 0.3582 ms | 27,129 B |
| New2 | 100000 | 8.205 ms | 0.1610 ms | 0.2458 ms | 13,008 B |
| New3 | 100000 | 7.725 ms | 0.1510 ms | 0.2439 ms | 13,072 B |
| Old | 100000 | 148.285 ms | 0.0301 ms | 0.0281 ms | - |
| New | 1000000 | 75.982 ms | 1.5130 ms | 2.4432 ms | 27,160 B |
| New2 | 1000000 | 76.613 ms | 1.5147 ms | 2.9900 ms | 13,008 B |
| New3 | 1000000 | 71.590 ms | 1.4137 ms | 3.1619 ms | 13,072 B |
| Old | 1000000 | 1,483.186 ms | 0.5073 ms | 0.4236 ms | 704 B |

<sub>***Disclaimer** : Obviously there are oodles of other parallel strategies you could try (linq based or otherwise) that would be worthy to benchmark, this was just an example*</sub>

<sub>***Supplemental** : before throwing more cores and threads at a problem, first you need to be sure you have a performance problem, and if you do make sure you are solving that problem as efficiently as possible first. There is no point using more threads to make an inefficient algorithm faster*</sub>

Comment: You need some kind of lock when checking and updating best variable (as per @alexei-levenkov comment)

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri all the code is fine and thread safe in every case :) assuming `CalculateFitness` is thread safe of course

Comment: That does not matter, if the best variable is updated right after checking the condition you can have the wrong result at the end of the loop.

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri I assume you're referring to `New3` ? if so, I have gone to great lengths to ensure it uses `Interlocked.CompareExchange` and that it checks for stale values, and that it updates it atomically regardless of instruction reordering

Comment: Actually, my comment was about the Old method. But I just observed that "best" is not related to fitness variable (double) but for the DNA class, so your whole examples need adjusting. The New3 method is strange, you need to calculate fitness before comparing no?

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri old is the ops code for comparison. also best is related to fitness :) Annnyway, i think this is going around in circles. The point of the answer was to show how this could be done in parallel, without using a lock (which because of contention would be slow), and how the op could measure this and any future strategy for success. ;)

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri you could be definitely right about the ordering, though it wouldn't make much difference to the outcome. Thanks

Comment: @TheGeneral - many thanks for your extensive answer. I am off to bed now but tomorrow I will check if I can implement this and it it works will mark this as the answer if nothing better is posted. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @TheGeneral - I am just now trying to implement your code. Just working for now with your method "New3". My problem is that I need to update the OBJECT "best". Your code seems to pass this as a double. That is why similar questions did not answer my problem - I need to update an object. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Fritz45 new3 is probably a little advanced, its definitely capable of updating the best object. Though in all honesty, the trouble it goes through to do its current logic, or to make it do the object switch is a little over kill, its only slightly faster than the others, Personally i would just go with one of the others. they are basically just as fast. However, more so, i suggest download benchmarkdotnet run the tests more realistic data. compared to what you had there might not be much difference, or a lot, however you dont know until you try it with a realistic scenario.

Comment: @Fritz45 ok i am a bit busy right now, you could try `var result =_population.First(x => x.fitness == TheDoubleValueYouGotFromMax);` its not the most optimal way of doing this, as it will iterate the list partially again. ill try and update this a bit later with an optimal appoach

Comment: @TheGeneral - no worries I was a bit intimidated by the LINQ syntax but then realized it can be done with a simple loop to find the object with the highest fitness. This is probably not optimal but since most of the work is done in the upper parallel loop, it is a small price to pay. I implemented your code - on my real life problem I get the same answer as the serial method, but your New2 method completes in 12mins vs the 37 mins that the serial method takes. So 3x improvement, which is great. Thanks so much for your help.